# do while loop exiting pre-maturely

Tags: c, do-while, avr

I have written code for reading switch status and exit if # is is pressed 3 times.

```
void allkeypadTest(void)
{
    static uint8_t modeKeyCount=0;

    do
    {
        uint8_t key=getKeyStatus();
        if(key)
        {
            if(key=='#')
            {
                modeKeyCount++;
                //pulseIODevice(LED1,1,500,200);
            }
            else
            {
                pulseIODevice(LED1,key-0x30,500,200);
            }
        }
     }while(modeKeyCount<3);
}
```

But as soon as I enter # key once, loop is exiting. Behavior is OK if I press other keys. However if I uncomment `pulseIODevice` present under `if(key=='#')` section, behavior is normal. `pulseIODevice` will toggle the LED for certain times at certain period and PWM passed to it. I am puzzled what went wrong in my code. Note that `getKeyStatus` will return `'\0'` (null) if no key is detected and return ASCII values of the keys of 1x4 keypad (ASCII values of 3, 6, 9 and # only)

Comment: The `getKeyStatus()` probably does not reset between calls? So it would do return `'#'` over and over again once you press it once.

Comment: Knowing the code of `getKeyStatus()` seems essential to answer this question, at least without wild guesses.

Comment: The loops seems to be faster than your fingertip ... :-)

Comment: when inputting such a value, after the value input is `#` must loop, checking the input, until the input is again NUL.   Then can start checking for a key press again.   Otherwise all three counts will be performed during a single key press

Comment: adding a delay between checking the returned value from `getKeyStatus()` just (almost) masks the problem.   Instead check to assure the finger is OFF the key before counting a key press again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason may be getkeyStatus() return "#" more than once when you press only one time. it is possible keypad device need some sleep time to clear its buffer memory i.e. as soon as you press a key its store into buffer which is getting multiple times.

Try

a. if possible printf("%c\n", key) and press only once and see how many times printed.

b. if any function to clear key functions ?  OR sleep(x ms).

c. when you uncomment pulseIODevice () its working normal may be due to pulseIODevice () blocks few milli seconds by that time pressed key cleared from keypad buffer.

Comment: Perfect. getKeyStatus() has a max key debounce delay of 50msec. So when I press the key, multiple key press is detected (I guess normal pressing by hand will be more than 200 msec. This is being a tactile key, I used to press long). Added delay and now it works fine.

Comment: @Rajesh: So if holding the key longer then the randomly hardcoded delay the code will fail again?

Answer (score 6):

After detecting the key state you might want to wait until it changed back to normal (no key pressed) before going on

To do so change

```
uint8_t key=getKeyStatus();
```

to be

```
uint8_t key = getKeyStatus();
while (0 != getKeyStatus())
{
  /* Do nothing. 
     Shouldn't loop too long if not abused by holding the key pressed. */
  /* if available add some milli sec delay here. */
}
```

A tiny bit more efficient and even more accurate would be

```
uint8_t key = getKeyStatus();
if ( 0 != key) 
{
  do 
  {
    /* Do nothing. 
       Shouldn't loop too long if not abused by holding the key pressed. */
    /* If available add some milli sec delay here. */
  } while (0 != getKeyStatus());
}
```

---

Background:

To detect an event ("key pressed" here) from a state's change ("key down", "key-up" here) by definition you need to test more than once.

Comment: Good Idea.  I will implement this so that no need to worry about the delay. Only in case we need to accept continuous keys actions like when we increment something, I need to take care with this delay.